# How to retrieve an object in javascript passed by php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajaxCall function that delete an image, and if the operation was done successfully, another function is called that remove the `div` which shows the image.

In variables which are passed to php, I try to pass that `div` object containing the image, and in success function I want to retrieve that object to remove it by javascript. But actually I don't know is it possible or no?! I have this error:`TypeError: $object.parent is not a function`

And this is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="imageID" id="imageID" value="1">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="a.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
    <a class="del-btn-pic" href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $(document).on("click",".del-btn-pic", function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var imageID = $this.parent().children('input').val();
        var divObject = JSON.stringify($this);
        ajaxCall('deleteImage', {object:divObject , imageID:imageID }, removeImageVisual)
    });
function removeImageVisual(data) // -> This function after ajaxCall is called. the php code in success returns the div object which passed before, and in failure returns 0.
{
    if(data != 0)
    {
        $divObject = JSON.parse(data);
        $divObject.parent().remove();
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Error!');
    }
}
```

Comment: in fact, in my code, I pass the object of `a` tag and retrieve it.(not `div` tag)

Comment: It looks fine untils the $divObject.parent(), what are you trying to achieve with that? $divObject must be a json object like {'name':'Javier'}, and it sure doesn't have a parent.

Comment: @Balder As I told in my comment, the code is a little different with my question unfortunately! actually devObject is the `a` tag!

Comment: if your data contains an a tag, then the JSON.parse will output a mistake, because conversion is not valid. Again, since you are pointing the whole data, you have no parent.

Comment: @balder Please explain more, what's the meaning of 'whole data'? so how can I do it correct?

Comment: I assume you 'data' variable from your success function has the HTML you wrote above, Am I right? This HTML is what I meant when I said "whole data", otherwise I would need to see the HTML inside the data variable to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61731/discussion-between-balder-and-highlan).

Comment: @Balder You're right

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing you should pass selector of `a` tag so that you can use in following manner.

```
var selector = JSON.parse(data);
$(selector).parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is remove the div after click on delete, but you dont have to send it to php and back to JS, because when you got back from php is a duplicate, just do like this:

```
$(document).on("click",".del-btn-pic", function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var imageID = $this.parent().children('input').val();
        //var divObject = JSON.stringify($this); not needed
        ajaxCall('deleteImage', {object:"" , imageID:imageID }, function(data) {
             removeImageVisual(data,imageID);
        });
    });


function removeImageVisual(data,imageID) 
{
    if(data != 0)
    {
        $('#' + imageID).parent().remove();
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Error!');
    }
}
```